# Memory leak in Eigen Conjugate Gradient?

Tags: memory-leaks, eigen, eigen3

I have spent the last day looking for a memory leak in my code. For each frame in my loop I can see in the task manager that about 200 Mb of memory is lost. Eventually the program of course crashes.

The pseudo-code looks like this:

```
 for frame = 0:NBROFFRAMES
     cv::Mat = getImage(frame);
     cout<<"Before optimization"<<endl;
     getchar();
     optFunction.optimizeColor(img);
     cout<<"After optimization"<<endl;
     getchar();
     Do other things
 end
```

Just looking in the task manager shows that in `optimizeColor` approximately 200 Mb are lost for every frame.

In `optimizeColor`I run `Eigens` `ConjugateGradient` several times. When I changed to `Cholesky Factorization, SimplicialLDLT`, the memory consumption is between `4.5-4.7 Gb` over the entire sequence. Using `ConjugateGradient` it starts with `4.5 Gb` and after `10` images the amount of memory used according to my Task Manager is `11.2 Gb`.

I have also run `Valgrind` and one of the messages I get is the following:

```
==22576== 110,430,720 bytes in 18 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 30,186 of 30,189
==22576==    at 0x4C2E80F: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==22576==    by 0x913CCD: Eigen::internal::scoped_array<int>::scoped_array(long) (Memory.h:666)
==22576==    by 0x910329: Eigen::internal::CompressedStorage<float, int>::reallocate(long) (CompressedStorage.h:230)
==22576==    by 0x910695: Eigen::internal::CompressedStorage<float, int>::resize(long, double) (CompressedStorage.h:96)
==22576==    by 0x91CC41: Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 0, int>& Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 0, int>::operator=<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 1, int> >(Eigen::SparseMatrixBase<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 1, int> > const&) (SparseMatrix.h:1085)
==22576==    by 0x91A911: Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 0, int>::SparseMatrix<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 1, int> >(Eigen::SparseMatrixBase<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 1, int> > const&) (SparseMatrix.h:674)
==22576==    by 0x91837C: void Eigen::Ref<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 0, int> const, 0, Eigen::OuterStride<-1> >::construct<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 1, int> >(Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 1, int> const&, Eigen::internal::false_type) (SparseRef.h:217)
==22576==    by 0x91631C: Eigen::Ref<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 0, int> const, 0, Eigen::OuterStride<-1> >::Ref<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 1, int> >(Eigen::SparseMatrixBase<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 1, int> > const&) (SparseRef.h:184)
==22576==    by 0x913801: void Eigen::internal::generic_matrix_wrapper<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 0, int>, false>::grab<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 1, int> >(Eigen::EigenBase<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 1, int> > const&) (IterativeSolverBase.h:81)
==22576==    by 0x90FEFE: void Eigen::IterativeSolverBase<Eigen::ConjugateGradient<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 0, int>, 3, Eigen::DiagonalPreconditioner<float> > >::grab<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 1, int> >(Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 1, int> const&) (IterativeSolverBase.h:375)
==22576==    by 0x90C03D: Eigen::ConjugateGradient<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 0, int>, 3, Eigen::DiagonalPreconditioner<float> >& Eigen::IterativeSolverBase<Eigen::ConjugateGradient<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 0, int>, 3, Eigen::DiagonalPreconditioner<float> > >::analyzePattern<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 1, int> >(Eigen::EigenBase<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float, 1, int> > const&) (IterativeSolverBase.h:199)
==22576==    by 0x9077F3: OptimizeAlbedo::optimize_rho(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1>, std::allocator<Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> > > const&, std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<int, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1>, std::allocator<Eigen::Matrix<int, 2, 1, 0, 2, 1> > > const&, Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const&, float, float, Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, 1, 0, -1, 1> const&) (OptimizeAlbedo.cpp:586)
```

The only thing I do that allocates memory is that I define the sizes of some matrices when I create the instance `optFunction` and reserve space for the entries. That is of course only done once and that I have checked several times. The only explanation I see is that `ConjugateGradient` is consuming memory.

Here is my code to call `ConjugateGradient`:

```
function optmize()
Eigen::ConjugateGradient<Eigen::SparseMatrix<float>, Eigen::Lower | Eigen::Upper> cg;
cg.setTolerance(0.001);
cg.setMaxIterations(200);
cg.analyzePattern(A_tot);
cg.factorize(A_tot);
Eigen::VectorXf opt = cg.solveWithGuess(b_tot, rho_current);
end
```

I would have expected that cg is cleared when the function goes out of scope, but it seems that is not the case.

I think I use `Eigen version: 3.2.92`, this is in the `Macros.h`:

```
#define EIGEN_WORLD_VERSION 3
#define EIGEN_MAJOR_VERSION 2
#define EIGEN_MINOR_VERSION 92
```

I am using `Ubuntu 16.04` and `g++ 5.4.0`.

EDIT: As pointed out by Avi Ginsburg, I was using a beta-version of Eigen. By upgrading to 3.3.2 it works without memory leaks.

Comment: That was a beta release. I would try using the current Eigen (3.3.2) and trying again.

Comment: Ok, I have just used sudo apt-get install, why does that give a beta version?

Comment: That was the version when Ubuntu 16.04 was released.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try with another version then.